# How to add a name to the gin route like laravel?

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to add a name to the gin route because I need to collect all the routes and display them on the page.
route.go

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/api/user/list", handler1)
    r.POST("/api/user/create",handle2)  
    r.Run()
}
```

This is the structure I need to collect：

```
var Routes []Route
type Route struct {
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Sign       string `json:"sign"`
    HttpMethod string `json:"http_method"`
    HttpPath   string `json:"http_path"`
}
```

What have I tried?
1.This is not an automatic method and requires manual maintenance of route names.

```
var RouteNameMap = map[string]string{
"api.user.list":"Get User List",
"api.user.create": "Create an User"
}

func ParseRoutes(r *gin.Engine, group string) {
    routes := r.Routes()
    for _, route := range routes {
        if strings.HasPrefix(route.Path, group) {
            sign := strings.Replace(strings.Trim(route.Path, "/"), "/", ".", -1)
            item := Route{
                Name:       RouteNameMap[sign],
                Sign:       sign,
                HttpMethod: route.Method,
                HttpPath:   route.Path,
            }
            Routes = append(Routes, item)
        }
    }
}
```

2. Use middleware, but this method needs to be obtained after requesting the route. I want to get all the data after the project is started.

3.Similar to the first method:

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    MyGET(r,"/api/user/list", handler1,"Get User List")
    MyPOST(r,"/api/user/create",handle2,"Create an User")
    r.Run()         
}

func MyPOST(engine *gin.Engine, path string, handlerFunc gin.HandlerFunc, name string) {
    engine.POST(path, handlerFunc)
    Routes = append(Routes, Route{
        Name:       name,
        Sign:       strings.Replace(strings.Trim(path, "/"), "/", ".", -1),
        HttpMethod: "POST",
        HttpPath:   path,
    })
}
output:
[{
        "name": "Get User List",
        "sign": "api.user.list",
        "http_method": "GET",
        "http_path": "/api/user/list"
    },
    {
        "name": "Create an User",
        "sign": "api.user.create",
        "http_method": "post",
        "http_path": "/api/user/create"
    }
]
```

But I feel that this method is not in line with the standards.I hope to add a similar name parameter to gin's POST and GET methods. And this name parameter can be parsed in the ParseRoutes method, what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what's wrong with the third method?

If the Route of the Gin framework does not provide parameters to set the `Name`, then you can only do this:

1. Submit code to the Gin framework and let the Gin framework support your needs;
2. Rewrite the Gin framework and abandon subsequent updates of the Gin framework;
3. Simply encapsulate a function yourself, just like your third method above.